# How convert a method to generic variant?

Tags: java, generics

I have defined this method in my interface

```
int[] sort(int[] unsortedArray);
```

now I want to change this to a more generic approach, so that any kind of type will be excepted. So I changed it to

```
<T>[] sort(<T>[]);
```

But this resolves in a compiler error.
Can someone explain my misunderstanding?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use `<T>` to declare that there is a generic type - you still need to use `T` to indicate return type, and the type of the parameter.

```
<T> T[] sort(T[] variable) {

}
```